# Using /etc/environment in Python virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, bottle, python-daemon

I am working on a daemon script that starts a bottle app using python-daemon package. The script is /etc/init.d/app.sh

There are some environment variables set in /etc/environment that are to be used in the application's settings.py file (os.environ).

As soon as I activate the virtualenv all the system environment variables are removed (including the ones that I have set in /etc/environment).

The init script I am using is

```
. /root/webapps/myapp/bin/activate

case "$1" in
    start)
    echo "Starting server"
    # Start the daemon 
    python /root/webapps/myapp/project/index.py start
    ;;
stop)
    echo "Stopping server"
    # Stop the daemon
    python /root/webapps/myapp/project/index.py stop
    ;;
restart)
    echo "Restarting server"
    python /root/webapps/myapp/project/index.py restart
    ;;
*)
    # Refuse to do other stuff
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/app {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Also when I check for the environment variables that I have defined in /etc/environment in ipython shell, variables show up fine. Only when I try to start the application using the init script, everything goes blank.

What I am looking for is a proper method of using variables defined in /etc/environment in my application inside virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the top of your `/etc/init.d/app.sh` script:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Then any and all environment variables set in `/etc/environment` should be seen by python  when you start the application using the init script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that also, but still the same. It is not working.

Comment: Can you do something like this: http://pythonwise.blogspot.com/2010/04/sourcing-shell-script.html immediately after activating the virtualenv?

Comment: I just figured out one more thing. This issue is only happening when I use "service app start" or "service app stop" and not happening when I use "/etc/init.d/app start" or "/etc/init.d/app stop".

Comment: That's because `service` removes all non-essential environment variables to make sure the init script runs in a clean environment. hope this means you're question is answered now!

Answer (score 0):

The activate script is nothing special, it just modifies your path. You can achieve the same in your launcher:

```
. /etc/environment
export PATH=/root/webapps/myapp/bin:$PATH
export VENV_BIN=/root/webapps/myapp/bin
export PROJECT_ROOT=/root/webapps/myapp/project

case "" in
    start)
    echo "Starting server"
    # Start the daemon 
    $VENV_BIN/python $PROJECT_ROOT/index.py start
    ;;
stop)
    echo "Stopping server"
    # Stop the daemon
    $VENV_BIN/python $PROJECT_ROOT/index.py stop
    ;;
restart)
    echo "Restarting server"
    $VENV_BIN/python $PROJECT_ROOT/index.py restart
    ;;
*)
    # Refuse to do other stuff
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/app {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found the issue. It is not related to init script. It is the "service" command that removes all the environment variables and runs the script in the minimum system environment.

Answer (score 0):

The link below provides interesting fix. I will be modifying my application to some extent to get it working

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables